# Agregar una opción estática en react-select

Tags: reactjs

Estoy trayendo las opciones de un dropdown de react-select de una api:

```
  const options = products.map(prod => {
    return { value: prod.category, label: prod.category }
  });
```

Este es el componente:

```
 <Select options={options} onChange={handleChangeCategory}/>
```

Quiero agregar una opción que diga "Todas las categorias" que no existe en la api, es decir una opción estática además de las ya existentes, algo así:

```
{ label: "Todas las categorias", value: 'all' }
```

¿Cómo puedo hacerlo? Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suponiendo que `options` es lo que pasas al `Select` (pese a que se llama `optionsCategory` en tu ejemplo...

```
const options = products.map(prod => {
    return { value: prod.category, label: prod.category }
  });

options.push({ label: "Todas las categorias", value: 'all'})
```

Suponiendo que quieres que all sea la primera opción

```
const options = [{ label: "Todas las categorias", value: 'all'}].concat(products.map(prod => {
    return { value: prod.category, label: prod.category }
  }));
```